# Who controls completing the circuit in a transistor?

Tags: semiconductor-physics, electronics, electrical-engineering

Consider an npn junction. The p-type semiconductor p has holes which are filled by electrons provided either by the n-type or by phosphorous dopants. The transfer of charge from n to p forms a depletion layer. Once the depletion layer is formed, if we have to cross electrons from one terminal to other, we have to apply positive voltage at p which results in completion of circuit. Who controls the positive voltage to be applied at p junction for completing the circuit?

Comment: The thing that the designer wanted to control it?

Answer (score -1):

Typically the gate signal which controls the conduction of the device is provided by sensor in an analog circuit , and the gate voltage is a function of the sensors measurement of the parameter being sensed. The device output in this case is variable from a minimum thru a maximum range,  representing the range of the parameter being measured. IN a switching function the gate is a fixed signal of constant potential provided as an input from some logical operation resulting in the required gate signal driving the device into full conduction mode. This is a two state gate signal,  IE on/off. Zero voltage (or voltage under that required to cause full conduction of the device) for no,  and forward bias voltage for a yes.